# python subprocess doesn't work with ssh command

Tags: python, ssh, subprocess

On my desktop, the following shell command lists the directories at root `/aa/*/bb/` on a remote server

```
ssh my_server 'echo /aa/*/bb/'
```

However, when I call it from python subprocess, it reports error

> CalledProcessError: Command '['ssh', 'my_server', 'echo /aa/*/bb/']' returned non-zero exit status 255

and the code is here

```
subprocess.check_output(['ssh', 'my_server', 'echo /aa/*/bb/'], shell=True)
```

However, if I log onto the remote server, and run

```
subprocess.check_output('echo /aa/*/bb/', shell=True)
```

It works.

What did I do wrong? Thank you very much for the help.

Comment: that's because `*` is expanded locally so the names don't match. Can you try `subprocess.check_output(['ssh', 'my_server', 'ls /'])` instead? almost the same output but at least it'll work

Comment: BTW, using `echo` to list files isn't ideal; you can't tell if you have two directories with spaces between them or one directory with a space in its name (and names can be even more surprising, including things like literal newline characters). If you're doing this programatically, use `printf '%s\0' /aaa/*/bb/` to get NUL-delimited output, which can be unambiguously parsed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `shell=True` prevents the argument from being passed. That's because:

```
subprocess.check_output(['ssh', 'my_server', 'echo /*/'], shell=True)
```

...runs the code:

```
# /- from shell=True
# |  ^  /- your first argument, becomes the script "sh -c" runs
# |  |  |   /- your second argument, becomes $0 to that script
# |  |  |   |         /- your third argument, becomes $1 to that script
# |  |  |   |         |
  sh -c ssh my_server 'echo /*/'
```

So, you're passing your shell script (which is only the exact string `ssh`) arguments $0 and $1, **but it doesn't read them at all**.

If you wanted this to work with `shell=True`, you could change it to:

```
#                        script      $0   $1           $2
subprocess.check_output(['ssh "$@"', '_', 'my_server', 'echo /*/'], shell=True)
```

but much better is just to leave that argument out:

```
subprocess.check_output(['ssh', 'my_server', 'echo /*/'])
```

Comment: ... as always: _never_ use `shell=True` except under duress :)

Comment: my pleasure. That was a very good explanation. Next time tell me when you're around so I won't attempt answering those :)

Comment: great depict worth thousand words :-)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you change your parameter to a **string** instead of a list, based on this section from the docs:

> On Unix with `shell=True`, the shell defaults to /bin/sh. If args is a string, the string specifies the command to execute through the shell. This means that the **string must be formatted exactly as it would be when typed at the shell prompt**. If args is a sequence, the first item specifies the command string, and any additional items will be treated as additional arguments to the shell itself. That is to say, Popen does the equivalent of:
>
> ```
> Popen(['/bin/sh', '-c', args[0], args[1], ...])
> ```

This will execute the command as you do manually (in a subshell):

```
subprocess.check_output('ssh my_server "echo /*/"', shell=True)
```

On another note, when using a sequence as the parameter **each item** needs to be a single item in the list, like that

```
subprocess.check_output(['ssh', 'my_server', 'echo', '/aa/*/bb/'], shell=True)
```

Comment: A list is perfectly valid with `shell=True`. It just isn't parsed the way the OP expects it to be. :)

Comment: ...in fact, you just ended your quote a few sentences before the docs describe how a list is treated. The problem with advising people to run `subprocess.check_output('ssh my_server "echo /*/"', shell=True)` is that usually, they'll produce that command using string concatenation, and if not done with care that leads to shell injection vulnerabilities (which is to say, security bugs), as described in the big red warning at https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments

Comment: So I strongly advise that people **not** pass a string if any parts of that string are assembled from variables rather than hardcoded.

Comment: I've added this part to complete my answer. I know list is a valid parameter, I recall I read somewhere that it is better to use string parameter when using the `shell=True`. I can't seem to find the source; does it have any preferance over the other?

Comment: so, I work in security, so that biases my priorities somewhat -- but passing data out-of-band from code is much safer than trying to substitute data *into* code, which can only be done safely if you escape it first (as with `pipes.quote()` in Python 2 or `shlex.quote()` in Python 3 to quote for safe shell consumption). Here, if you're trying to pass something through `ssh` safely, it actually needs to go through *two* rounds of parsing, one by the local shell and one by the shell started by `ssh`.

Comment: so, let's say that you want to look at `/somedir/*/` instead of just `/*/`, and where both `somedir` and the hostname are coming from a Python variable. Doing that with untrusted variables is a lot messier even *without* `shell=True`; it needs to look something like: `subprocess.Popen(['ssh', hostname, 'echo %s' % pipes.quote('/%s/*/' % somedir)])`

Comment: doing it safely *with* `shell=True` and passing a string might be more like `subprocess.Popen(' '.join([pipes.quote(x) for x in ['ssh', hostname, ' '.join(pipes.quote(x) for x in ['echo', '/%s/*/' % somedir]]]])` (note that the directory name is quoted *twice*, once to be unescaped by the remote shell, once to be unescaped by the local shell).

Comment: ...if you *don't* do that, someone manipulating your code to look for children of a `somedir` with `$(rm -rf ~)'$(rm -rf ~)'` in its name could cause you a very bad day.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough explanation, this looks unreadable and not so pythonic. There has to be a better way in python :) I avoid using the `shell=True` parameter and let python do it's thing

Comment: Sure -- it'd be a lot more readable if I could define some functions instead of repeating myself, but a comment box has its limitations. I definitely agree that avoiding `shell=True` is the right thing wherever possible. (Actually, if you used `bash -c` as the shell, you could then use `printf %q` to have the shell itself do the same escaping that Python's `pipes.quote()` does, so you could make it the local shell's problem to do the extra escaping for the benefit of the remote shell started by `ssh`... but still best to just avoid the whole problem).

Comment: With respect to your last "other note", by the way -- it's true in 99% of cases, but `ssh` is a special case. For all the arguments passed to the remote server, ssh just concatenates them together with spaces into a single string and passes that string to `ssh -c`. Thus, in either `['ssh', 'hostname', 'echo', 'hello', 'world']` or `['ssh', 'hostname', 'echo hello world']`, ssh puts all the remote arguments together into one (identical) string. (For that reason, I tend to suggest forming the string yourself; it's more explicit to the reader).